# Syntax error in argument list of a subroutine

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I am trying to compile a code using gfortran. The subroutine `plumed_f_gcmd` is where I am having some trouble. Here is the piece of the code

```
        call plumed_f_gcmd("setMDTimeUnits"//char(0),timeUnits)
        call plumed_f_gcmd("setPlumedDat"//char(0),"plumed.dat"//char(0))
        call plumed_f_gcmd("setLogFile"//char(0),"PLUMED.OUT"//char(0))
        call plumed_f_gcmd("setNatoms"//char(0),natms)
        call plumed_f_gcmd("setMDEngine"//char(0),"dlpoly1.90"//char(0))
```

the compiler throws the following error:

```
call plumed_f_gcmd("setPlumedDat"//char(0),"plumed.dat"//char(0
                                                               1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)

call plumed_f_gcmd("setMDEngine"//char(0),"dlpoly1.90"//char(0)
                                                               1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

First of all I don't quite understand how in a subroutine, the second input can be once a number and once a string? does `'//char(0)'` somehow changes the string to another data type? Can someone please explain this to me?

And my second question is why the error is not happening also for the case of the third line (PLUMED.OUT)?

I don't know how but some C and C++ wrappers are also involved; this is the subroutine in C:

```c
void plumed_f_gcmd(char*key,void*val){
   plumed_gcmd(key,val);
}
```

Comment: To me that looks like you're exceeding the permitted line lengths.  Is this meant to be fixed-form source (what's the file extension/command line)?

Comment: In fixed form as here, characters after column 72 are ignored.

Comment: Yes, changes made by LRiO are destructive, I am rolling them back.

Comment: @francescalus: FORTRAN requires eight spaces at the start of each line? TIL. That's fine. I really don't see why it matters here as the context is utterly clear and all that space does is waste pixels, but that's fine.

Comment: @SergeyA: Unfortunately, you also rolled back the syntax highlighting fix, so now the code is being rendered as if it were C++, which is obviously wrong and very confusing when you look at the code with your eyes. Why did you choose to do that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, would you please fix the highlight but leave spaces in place? (Changes to syntax were inadvertent) Fortran doesn't require a specific number of spaces, but it is position-dependent language, which wants certain symbols in certain poistions and has limits on line length.

Comment: @SergeyA: Yes, that's precisely what I just did. Why did you put the spaces back but break the highlight?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, accidentally. I was focused on spaces.

Comment: You can use the `-ffree-form` option to tell `gfortran` to compile the code as free format despite any assumption it might otherwise make from the filename extension.  This is not necessarily a hole-in-one, however, as there are other differences between fixed- and free-format source than just line lengths.  You might instead just conform to fixed format by, say, moving the second argument to each call to a continuation line.

Comment: Note, too, that the function signature you provided for the C wrapper looks quite wrong for interfacing with `gfortran`, or with any other Fortran for which I've ever done C interfacing.  The function name probably needs to be mangled, the second argument type is incorrect, and for each `CHARACTER` argument on the Fortran side, you need a corresponding extra `int` parameter that gives its length.

Comment: the posted question has nothing to do with `c` nor `c++`  strongly suggest removing those tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the error message

> Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)

appears most likely because your Fortran code is written in fixed-format and only the first 72 characters are processed by the compiler. To avoid this, please try an option like

```
gfortran -ffixed-line-length-none yourcode.f
```

which allowa lines of any length. The reason why no error occurs for the third line (with "PLUMED.OUT") is probably that the line is within 72 characters (but very close!)

---

As for `char(0)` (the null character), this is attached to Fortran strings so that they can be processed by C routines as a [null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). Please note that `//` in Fortran represents a string concatenation (similar to `"hello" + "world"` in other languages), not some special thing that changes the string to another data type.

---

As for why the second argument of `plumed_f_gcmd()` can be once a number and once a string, I guess this routine probably reads the first argument (or "command") and makes an appropriate type casting in some routine (please see the original [code](http://plumed.github.io/doc-v2.0/developer-doc/html/_plumed_8c_source.html#l00264) for details). The following is such an example, where integer, real, and string variables are passed to the same routine `sub()`:

fort.f90:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer       :: intval
    real          :: realval
    character(50) :: str

    intval = 777 ; realval = 3.14 ; str = "world"

    call sub( "ShowInteger" // char(0), 100    )
    call sub( "ShowInteger" // char(0), intval )

    call sub( "ShowReal"    // char(0), 1.0     )
    call sub( "ShowReal"    // char(0), realval )

    call sub( "ShowString"  // char(0), "hello"   // char(0) )
    call sub( "ShowString"  // char(0), trim(str) // char(0) )
end
```

sub.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sub_ ( char* cmd, void* ptr )
{
    printf( "command = %s\n", cmd );

    if ( strcmp( cmd, "ShowInteger" ) == 0 ) printf( "int   : %20d\n",   *((int*)ptr) );
    if ( strcmp( cmd, "ShowReal"    ) == 0 ) printf( "float : %20.5f\n", *((float*)ptr) );
    if ( strcmp( cmd, "ShowString"  ) == 0 ) printf( "str   : %20s\n",    (char*)ptr ); 
}
```

Compile

```
gfortran -c fort.f90
gcc -c sub.c
gfortran fort.o sub.o
```

Result

```
command = ShowInteger
int   :                  100
command = ShowInteger
int   :                  777
command = ShowReal
float :              1.00000
command = ShowReal
float :              3.14000
command = ShowString
str   :                hello
command = ShowString
str   :                world
```

(Please note that the above C routine may not be portable for compilers other than gcc/gfortran. To make it portable, please use the interoperability features of modern Fortran, e.g., this [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperable-Subroutines-and-Functions.html)).